# how to validate for money in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

how to validate for money in jquery where max amount i can enter is 9999.99
so my requirements are:
1.it should allow only digits and one dot
2.max length is 7(including dot)
3.before dot max length is 4
4.after dot max length is 2

currently my textbox allows only digits and one dot with the following code

```
$('#txtpaymentamnt, #txttenderamt').on("keypress", function (e) {
    alert(e.which);
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which != 46)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to check input value on event (for example, button click) or prevent entering wrong data ?

Comment: text box leave event or prevent entering wrong data(but should pop up a message saying max amnt is 9999.99)

Comment: If you are using html5 u can have <input type="number"> and use the min and max properties

Comment: I am using MVC and no <input>.only @html.EditorFor

Comment: If u are using Mvc why dont u use DataAnnotations?

Comment: Please only use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when using the jQuery Validation plugin.  Edited.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression: `/^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/`

EDIT:

Here's the requested [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/vY39r/)

Comment: I updated the regular expression and added a fiddle.

Comment: thanks Jack Zelig ...it worked for me,but need to change for not accepting alphabets

Comment: It tries to match zero to four digits, an optional decimal point followed by zero to two digits. Letters won't match and will be rejected. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: hey it works now JackZelig...I guess i missed something..thanks much :)

Comment: The fiddle removes the last character even if that wasn't the character your entered incorrectly. I've updated to improve on this, but it's still not perfect. http://jsfiddle.net/vY39r/171/

Comment: @DeadPassive the jsfiddle you provided put undefined in the input box if the first character inputted isn't valid. I fixed it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w0jekdL6/

Comment: freakin awesome example, does exactly what I needed.

Comment: how can set not allow input dot (.) character

Comment: Just remove it from the regex: `/^\d{0,4}(\d{0,2})?$/`

Comment: your solution is well suited to me, but when I check against input type number it didn't work. Couldn't fix the issue...

Comment: That's a shame. If you can fit your code into a comment, let me know and I'll have a look. Otherwise, maybe post a new question.

Answer (score 11):

With [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) you can set your own rule using Jack's regular expression (which I haven't tested though) like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "money",
    function(value, element) {
        var isValidMoney = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(value);
        return this.optional(element) || isValidMoney;
    },
    "Insert "
);
```

Then you can set the rule within using the validate method:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
rules: {
    nameOfMyInputField: {
        money: true,
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I updated the regular expression which has been updated by Jack Zelig in his post.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd use [the isNumeric function in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/964807) to check if the input is a number and then check if the number is valid for your case.

To ve a "valid number" (according to your requirements), it has to:

- Be between 0 and 9999.99 (maximum of 4 digits before the dot).
- Have a maximum of 2 decimal digits. A good way to check that is to truncate the number after the nth digit (in your case, the second one) and compare it to the original value(two different values mean the second number has more decimal digits than the first). Use `Math.round(number*100)/100` to truncate everything after the second decimal digit.

I hope this helps you with your problems.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if you are using `MVC`. `MVC` framework provides `annotations` which can be used to best effects. Even if there is no explicit data annotation for a `decimal`.

Following can be used for Two Decimal places

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$")]
```

And for range you can use

```
[Range(0, 9999.99)]
```

So your model field becomes

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$")]
[Range(0, 9999.99)]
public decimal Money{ get; set; }
```

Hope It Helps